# How can I easily adapt my existing Android app to Honeycomb?

Tags: android, mobile, android-3.0-honeycomb

Currently I have an app which works on Android 1.6 and above, works on QVGA screens upwards. I'd rather not have to rewrite a separate application for Honeycomb and I can't find much help anywhere. Is there an easy way for me to adapt it to work on Android 3.0+ with a proper tablet interface rather than just magnifying my Android-phone interface. I've noticed there is something called fragments, but they seem to involve a major rewrite? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it's all about Fragments. To make a nice app that makes full use of a large screen and of course a small screen the layouts will be different. Fragments help to break up you UI and make it easier to have larger screens use more pieces of your UI (fragments).

Generally it isn't a big change moving from Activities and Views to using Fragments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And for those who are looking for an example, I finally managed to dig one up http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Comment: For a look into the design side of this process, see this talk from Google I/O earlier this year: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/designing-and-implementing-android-uis-for-phones-and-tablets.html and the Google I/O 2011 schedule app source illustrating these ideas is available here: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout